# How to display records of last year and current year at once?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display records from MySQL of last year and current year at once, but after last record of last year I want to include picture. In MySQL row (date) have timestamp.

```
    $messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uzsakymai WHERE seen='yes' ORDER BY date DESC");
    if (date("Y", $messages['date']) == "2015") {
        echo '<div class="rounded"><img src="images/orders.png"/></div>';
    }
    while ($im = mysql_fetch_assoc($messages)) {
        echo '<div class="reply-avatar float-left"><img src="images/'.$im['user_avatar'].'" /></div>
        <div>
            <div class="username float-left">'.$im['username'].'</div>
            <small class="post-date float-left"> <img src="http://beltup.org.uk/images/assets/stats-hours.png" /> '.laikas($im['date']).'</small>
        </div>';
    }
```

It must to be something like that:

- 2016 year records:
- Picture
- 2015 year records.

Any ideas how to do that? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: just select between the first day of 2015 and last day of 2016

Comment: Ok, but how I can include picture after last record of 2015?

Comment: just add a flag of 2016 under the loop, a simple boolean should suffice

Comment: @Ghost, Thanks for your answer. :)